# Error en datatable generada con AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Buenas noches he generado una tabla con datatable y la respuesta de un ajax. Pero tengo un problema, tengo un icono que se muestra en el caso de haber mensajes en la base de datos relacionada con esa fila de la tabla. El problema es que el icono solo se muestra en la primera página, en el resto aunque si que hay mensajes no muestra el icono.

```
columns: [
{ data: null, render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                            
   if(data.mensajes_de_usuarios.length !== 0){
      $('#losMensajes_'+ data.id +'').html('<a href="#verMensajes_'+ data.id +'" data-user="'+ data.id +'" data-toggle="modal" class="mydrop2a" style="color: #7460ee;" data-target="#verMensajes_'+ data.id +'" id="'+ data.id +'"><i class="far fa-comment-alt"></i></a>');
   }
   return '<span id="losMensajes_'+ data.id +'"></span><button type="button" class="btnMovil mydrop2a" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="'+ data.telefono +'" data-animation="false"><i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i></button><div style="position: relative; display:inline-block;">\
       <a href="#verhistoriaCliente'+ data.id +'" data-user="'+ data.id +'" data-toggle="modal" class="mydrop2a abrModal" data-target="#verhistoriaCliente'+ data.id +'" id="'+ data.id +'">\
          <i class="fas fa-history"></i>\
       </a>\
       <a class="mydrop2a" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">\
          <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i>\
       </a>\
       <div class="dropdown-menu drop22" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">\
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="clientes-potenciales/ver-cliente/'+ data.id +'">\
             <li>\
                <i class="far fa-eye"></i> Visualizar\
             </li>\
          </a>\
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="clientes-potenciales/editar/'+ data.id +'">\
             <li>\
                <i class="far fa-edit"></i> Editar\
             </li>\
          </a>\
        </div>\
     </div>';
     }}
 ],
```

Como podeis ver compruebo si el arreglo no viene vacio, siendo así hago un append en el return, pero nada solo funciona en la primera página. ¿Qué puede ser?

Comment: y cual es el error???

Comment: No me traer error alguno, simplemente el icono no se muestra

Comment: según veo el icono solo lo insertas una vez..

Comment: He probado con append también y me sucede lo mismo

Comment: pero es que esos metodos solo insertan una vez el elemento ... que se supone deberia pasar???

Comment: ya se cual es el problema... creo que estas intentando agregar el boton dentro del renderizado .... no deberia ser despues del renderizado???

Comment: Exacto @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent pero si lo pongo después del render, ni lo detecta

Comment: incluso si armas en tu backend el html que muestras en datatable por que no armas los botones ??

Comment: si detectarlo has hecho la prueba??

Comment: He probado a ponerlo después de return, pero ahí no me muestra nada

Comment: los return finalizan los metodos y callbacks XD

Comment: tendrias que ver si datatable tiene un metodo para saber cuando se finaliza el renderizado de una tabla para ejecutar otra cosa

Comment: por hay vi que con `.on('draw',` https://stackoverflow.com/a/60542433/17161735

Comment: Pero como utilizo este fragmento `table.on( 'draw', function () {` dentro del data??

Comment: no no eso seria un evento aparte fuera del renderisado de la tabla ...

Comment: Y como le hago entender que es en esa columna? , no comprendo como utilizarlo

Comment: agregaste solo un pedazo de código ... si quieres ayuda deberías de agregar el código completo y como consigues los datos ... un ejemplo de los datos ... un ejemplo mínimo reproducible vendría bien.

Comment: Entiendo, no lo hice por que es muy largo todo. Voy a ver como lo hago

Comment: te falta leer mas la documentacion en la documentacion esta toda la informacion de como insertar elementos a una datatable...

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar un ejemplo de datos, de un par de filas, una con  y otra sin mensajes.